# Who passes value to data, response, error in dataTask in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am reading the following code. I can identify there is a closure. I don't understand who pass the value into `data, response, error`.

```
 let dataTask = self.session.dataTaskWithURL(url,
            { (data, response, error) in
                if (error == nil) {
                doseomthing()
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'who passes?' That is a closure which you get the data as callback. Read closure document - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: I mean I don't know thats going on between GET HTTP response and data, response, error get values.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS Foundation framework's networking code makes the HTTP request and then, when it completes some time later (either successfully or with an error), calls your closure, passing the `data`, `response` and `error` parameters. The value of those parameters tell your closure code what happened.